# SQL Query to find and remove characters

Tags: sql, replace, ssis, trim

I am importing data from a flat file to a SQL table called TCVS_tmp_PO_Detail using SSIS and SQL. Now and then I get some characters in the Purchase Order column that I would like to find and eliminate if they occur.

The characters are ï»¿, so could I trim these 3 characters on the left of the number out? It does not occur all the time so I can run it on the front end of my SSIS job as a query to correct it before exporting it.

Here is an example of what it looks like when it occurs

```
Purchase Order
7
7
8
8
8
8
8
8
9
10
10
10
10
11
12
13
11
12
13
14
14
15
15
16
16
17
19
18
ï»¿19
20
22
```

Comment: Those chars look like a bad encoding: UTF-8 text treated as (extended-)ASCII or probably stored in a varchar column (instead of nvarchar). Is it always the same line?

Comment: It is always in the same line but it only occurs now and then like maybe twice a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where the data lies for the processing, but you can easily do this with a `case` expression:

```
 (case when purchase_order like 'ï»¿%' then stuff(purchase_order, 1, 3, '')
       else purchase_order
  end) as purchase_order
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use "Data Flow Task"

1. Add "Derived Column" component 
   [image]
2. Add new column
3. Add this code to the Expression

   `REPLACE(Purchase,"ï»¿","")`

**The results:**

[image]